# Astropy.times doesn't recognise entries as strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, astropy

I am using astropy.times to convert Dates of the format 2013-11-01.5037738 to JD or MJD.
The dates are stored in a dataframe. The problem is, that astropy.times only accepts strings as entry which is not the case yet because the dates are just stored in the column as objects. I also tried reading them with astropy like that but this didn't work:

`t = time.Time(rad['UTDate'], format='isot', scale='utc')`

This yields the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/mambaforge/envs/AstroData/lib/python3.9/site-packages/astropy/time/core.py:491, in TimeBase._get_time_fmt(self, val, val2, format, scale, precision, in_subfmt, out_subfmt)
    490 try:
--> 491     return cls(val, val2, scale, precision, in_subfmt, out_subfmt)
    492 except UnitConversionError:

File ~/mambaforge/envs/AstroData/lib/python3.9/site-packages/astropy/time/formats.py:119, in TimeFormat.__init__(self, val1, val2, scale, precision, in_subfmt, out_subfmt, from_jd)
    118 else:
--> 119     val1, val2 = self._check_val_type(val1, val2)
    120     self.set_jds(val1, val2)

File ~/mambaforge/envs/AstroData/lib/python3.9/site-packages/astropy/time/formats.py:1271, in TimeString._check_val_type(self, val1, val2)
   1270 if val1.dtype.kind not in ('S', 'U') and val1.size:
-> 1271     raise TypeError(f'Input values for {self.name} class must be strings')
   1272 if val2 is not None:

TypeError: Input values for isot class must be strings

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [333], line 1
----> 1 t = time.Time(rad['UTDate'], format='isot', scale='utc')
      2 t

File ~/mambaforge/envs/AstroData/lib/python3.9/site-packages/astropy/time/core.py:1580, in Time.__init__(self, val, val2, format, scale, precision, in_subfmt, out_subfmt, location, copy)
   1578         self._set_scale(scale)
   1579 else:
-> 1580     self._init_from_vals(val, val2, format, scale, copy,
   1581                          precision, in_subfmt, out_subfmt)
   1582     self.SCALES = TIME_TYPES[self.scale]
   1584 if self.location is not None and (self.location.size > 1
   1585                                   and self.location.shape != self.shape):

File ~/mambaforge/envs/AstroData/lib/python3.9/site-packages/astropy/time/core.py:433, in TimeBase._init_from_vals(self, val, val2, format, scale, copy, precision, in_subfmt, out_subfmt)
    430 mask, val, val2 = _check_for_masked_and_fill(val, val2)
    432 # Parse / convert input values into internal jd1, jd2 based on format
--> 433 self._time = self._get_time_fmt(val, val2, format, scale,
    434                                 precision, in_subfmt, out_subfmt)
    435 self._format = self._time.name
    437 # Hack from #9969 to allow passing the location value that has been
    438 # collected by the TimeAstropyTime format class up to the Time level.
    439 # TODO: find a nicer way.

File ~/mambaforge/envs/AstroData/lib/python3.9/site-packages/astropy/time/core.py:499, in TimeBase._get_time_fmt(self, val, val2, format, scale, precision, in_subfmt, out_subfmt)
    494 except (ValueError, TypeError) as err:
    495     # If ``format`` specified then there is only one possibility, so raise
    496     # immediately and include the upstream exception message to make it
    497     # easier for user to see what is wrong.
    498     if len(formats) == 1:
--> 499         raise ValueError(
    500             f'Input values did not match the format class {format}:'
    501             + os.linesep
    502             + f'{err.__class__.__name__}: {err}'
    503         ) from err
    504     else:
    505         problems[name] = err

ValueError: Input values did not match the format class isot:
TypeError: Input values for isot class must be strings
```

Therefore I tried to just convert the column like this:
`rad['UTDate'] = rad['UTDate'].apply(lambda x: f'"{x}"').astype('string')`

Which worked because it seemed like astropy needs the '' around the values. Unfortunately reading the column like that again still yields the same error.
I tried also:
Converting the column to a numpy array and also using it as a list to plug it into astropy. Still the same error. Using the values one by one raises no error and creates the correct time.
Here an example:
In:`time.Time("2013-11-01.5037738", format='isot', scale='utc')`
Out:`<Time object: scale='utc' format='isot' value=2013-11-01T00:00:00.504>`

Comment: Maybe using a cast like `str(rad['UTDate'].apply(lambda x: f'"{x}"').astype('string'))` ?

Comment: This makes them object type again and the rows have this format: `"2013-11-01.5037738"\n1 `

Comment: Have you had a look at `strftime()` in astropy ? https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/time/index.html

Comment: But I saw now that .apply(lambda x: f'"{x}"') is not needed because when I print the column entries one by one after just applying .astype('string') they will print with '', unfortunately this is not shown if I just print the whole column. But anyhow also changing that raises the same error.

Comment: Not yet but I will try it now.

Comment: When you say that `Time("2013-11-01.5037738", format='isot', scale='utc')` works for you, are you sure? It doesn't work for me and I get the `ValueError: Time 2013-11-01 does not match isot format` (astropy version 5.2.2).

Comment: strftime() won't work because for it I have to read my data with Time() which is raising the error I have.

Comment: @MattPitkin Yes that works for me somehow. Also if I change the format from isot to iso. But maybe this is the problem then. If this is not meant to work with this format which format do I have to use then?

Comment: What version of astropy are you using then? If I have correctly formatted isot times, then e.g., `rad = pd.DataFrame({"UTDate": ["2013-11-01T00:00:00.5037738", "2014-11-01T00:00:00.5037738", "2015-11-01T00:00:00.5037738"]})`, followed by `time.Time(rad["UTDate"].to_list(), format="isot", scale="utc")` works for me.

Comment: What is the decimal `.5037738` supposed to represent in your time string? Is it a fraction of a day given the preceding date string?

Comment: The error is irritating but the problem is that I plug in a dataframe column. Just defining `test = list(rad['UTDate].astype('string'))`and plugging that in solved it.
But still thanks for the help. It's always the small things like that...

Comment: If the isot formatting does become an issue for you, and the value from the decimal point onwards is a fraction of a data, then you could do: `dates = [time.Time(d.split(".")[0], format="iso", scale="utc") + time.TimeDelta(float(f"0.{d.split('.')[1]}")) for d in rad["UTDate"].to_list()]`.

Comment: @LeoPfeiffer - the time "2013-11-01.5037738" is not compliant with `isot` format and this is reflected in the first part of your exception message. So I'm surprised that for you it parses with astropy.time. You should be very suspicious of the results in that case. Also, note that this fractional date format is tricky for days with a leap second if you care about accuracy to better than a second.